# Firefox and IE browser not taking input for text field(WebDriver Manager)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to lunch the Firefox and IE browser using Selenium WebDriver Manager.
It Successfully launched and Entered the URL.

But without entering the data into the text field it clicks the next button.
Using :

Webdriver Version = 3.1.1

Selenium =Latest Version

Firefox browser in my local system = 59.0

IE browser in my local system =11.3.7

```
if(browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){

        driverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    }else if(browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){

        driverManager.iedriver().setup();

        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

}


driver.manage().window().maximize();    

driver.get(url);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator")).sendKeys("test");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("next")).click();
```

Comment: If the next button is getting clicked then definately there is something wrong with the textbox Xpath locator. Please cross check and verify it.

Comment: Hi, I tried the same locator in the chrome and edge browser it is working fine. even I highlight the locator in firefox browser its find correctly.

Comment: Debug and check the execution line by line.